# useeffect proper use with async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a component with infinite scrolling, which calls fetchList, but when the user wants to refresh the list and clicks on the search button again, that should reset the userlist state, how to do this properly with hooks?

```
  const fetchList = async () => {
    setState(prevState => ({...prevState,loading:true }));
    //postdata settings,etc here
    const responseJson = await context.api(  ...... );
    //...
            setState(prevState => {
                let userlist = prevState.userlist;
                //push new users to userlist here..
                return {...prevState,userlist: userlist, nextPage: responseJson.data.nextPage,loading:false}
            });
  }


Search button onclick:
  const startSearch =()=> {
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, nextPage: 0,userlist:[],newsearch:1}));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(searchstate.newsearch)
    {
      fetchList();
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState, newsearch:0}));   
    }
  },[searchstate.newsearch]);
```

Is there a better way to do this?
With classes, I would simply do this with a callback:

```
    startSearch = async ()=> {
        this.setState({nextPage:0, userlist:[]}, this.fetchList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify what you've got a little by moving your logic to `startSearch`, but you're still going to need a useEffect to call fetchList. I've gone ahead and split up "nextPage" into "nextPage" and "pageToRender". It's roughly the same as what you have, but I think a little easier to read:

```
  // any time the pageToRender changes, let's fetch it
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchList();
  }, [searchstate.pageToRender]);

  // this resets our search and kicks off a re-fetching of the first page
  const startSearch = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      nextPage: 0,
      pageToRender: 0,
      userlist: []
    }));
  };

  // will increment pageToRender, loading the next page.
  // You may want to ensure ordering in case two calls
  // to increment are resolved in the wrong order.
  const increment = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      pageToRender: prevState.nextPage
    }));
  };
```

Comment: I wrote that: "With classes, I would simply do this with a callback:" But with hooks, callback not working!const [searchstate, setState]=useState(
        initialState
    );

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I've updated accordingly, but it's less pretty.